# Crazy automatic float rounding in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, floating-point

My exact MySQL version is `5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1`.
And I'm beginning to think that I'm getting crazy...

Just try these queries:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `float_bug` (
  `v` FLOAT NOT NULL
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

```sql
INSERT INTO float_bug VALUES(92160596);
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM float_bug;
```

Returns `92160600`.

Then I tried these:

```sql
SELECT * FROM float_bug WHERE v = 92160596;
SELECT * FROM float_bug WHERE v BETWEEN 92160596 AND 92160600;
```

Both return nothing!

However this

```sql
SELECT * FROM float_bug WHERE v = 92160592;
```

Returns `92160600`.

I'm ready to throw my computer into the wall, but unfortunately that won't help because I have exactly the same behaviour on my remote server and I can't throw it into the wall physically.

Any ideas what is going on here?

Comment: Did you try using `OR`  instead of `AND` in your `SELECT * FROM float_bug WHERE v = 92160596 AND 92160600;` statement? Alternative might be to try `SELECT * FROM float_bug WHERE v BETWEEN 92160595  AND 92160601` (I specifically added/subtracted 1 from the initial values). By the way: This is a pretty good looking first question. Congratulations and welcome to DBA.SE.

Comment: thanks @Johnakahot2use, it was a typo :) fixed with `BETWEEN`. I've already found the answer. It was `float` type not allowing more than 7 digits.

Comment: @mustaccio thanks but you referred the same what I posted in my own answer :)

Comment: Doesn't make it any less of a dupe

Comment: @mustaccio even though the source of the issues is the same the questions are different IMHO. That's why I won't confirm it's a duplicate.

Comment: Converting float to hex and back:  92160592 --> 4cafc84a --> 92160592 -----
92160594 --> 4cafc84a --> 92160592 -----
92160596 --> 4cafc84a --> 92160592 -----
92160598 --> 4cafc84b --> 92160600 -----
92160600 --> 4cafc84b --> 92160600

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I've found an answer :))

https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/144990/172761

> `FLOAT` stores 24 significant bits of data (equivalent to about **7
>   decimal digits**; storage=4 bytes), with an exponent ranging over about
>   10 ** +/-38.

So bad it's not stated in official MySQL docs. At least I couldn't find it after checking all articles about floating numbers.

Comment: 10^7 < 2^24 < 10^8, which means 7 digits - what else?

Comment: @Akina well in the docs it's stated very vaguely. There is no word that `float` stores only 24 significant bits of data. If it were at least 27 bits my numbers would fit :)))

Comment: *There is no word that float stores only 24 significant bits of data.* [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  Floating-Point Types (Approximate Value) - FLOAT, DOUBLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html): *A precision from 0 to 23 results in a 4-byte single-precision FLOAT column.* Plus 1st bit which exists always => 24 bits max.

Comment: @Akina this is what I call "stated very vaguely"

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-syntax.html

Comment: @Akina - That "0 to 23..." referred to `p` in `FLOAT(p)`.  The link I give is less vague.  The IEEE standard is 754 -- if anyone wants more gory details.

Answer (score 2):

This is not just a SQL thing: floating-point numbers should always be considered approximations in *any* language. See https://floating-point-gui.de/ amongst other references.

You can use the DOUBLE type instead which would help, as that can represent integers up to 53 bits in length accurately, but you would have problems later with bigger numbers.

Unless you absolutely must have floating-point numbers, these types should be avoided. Use integer (int, bigint, ...) or fixed-point types (decimal, numeric) instead. As you don't say what you are using these numbers to represent we can't make a more specific recommendation.

Comment: well I knew about floating-point problems but it's first time I face a situation where a number gets rounded to 2 signs BEFORE the floating point. This case was rather related to storage limitations than to floating-math problems.

Comment: Yeah, most discussions on the subject talk about the "classic" 0.1+0.2≠0.3 encounter so a lot of people who read the intro & examples but not the detailed explanation assume that it only affects to the right of the decimal point. The key to remember is that the limitation is significant digits, not specifically decimal places. Explanations tend to be written assuming a level of maths intuition that would make that obvious, but for a lot of self-taught coders that isn't ingrained.

Comment: well I'm not a self-taught, I have a Computer-Science degree and even learned IEEE-754 in details but that didn't save me from getting caught on this issue ))